# One parameter change of a section of $T^*M \otimes End(TM)$ on an affinely flat manifold

Tags: connections, affine-geometry

Let $\nabla$ be a flat symmetric connection in the tangent bundle of a smooth manifold $M.$ Let $A$ be a global section of $T^*M \otimes End(TM).$ Let $\phi:B(0,1) \to M$ be  a local affine chart on $M$ defined on the ball of radius $1$ centered at the origin in $\mathbb{R}^n.$ Let $(\partial_i)_{i=1,n}$ be the local frame induced in $TM.$ 
Consider the local matrix of $1$ forms defined by

$$ A(\partial_i(x))=A_i^j (x) \otimes \partial_j(x),$$ where $x \in B(0,1).$

Is it true that for a fixed $t$ ($0 < t \leq 1$), there exist a unique global section of $T^*M \otimes End(TM),$ denoted $A^t$ that satisfies $$ A^t(\partial_i(x))=tA_i^j (tx) \otimes \partial_j(x),$$ for all  $x \in B(0,1)?$

Comment: What is your question? To prove the last statement?